# Do I have to pay a fee to develop or deploy a .NET application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, payment

I have heard that .NET is not free and that I have to pay Microsoft if I develop a .NET application.  Is this true?  If so:

1. What do I have to pay?
2. I'm a subscriber to the MSDN via the Academic Alliance (we download a variety of Microsoft Software products for free, like VS2008 and Windows Server 2008). Do I have to pay for the software that I make with these tools?
3. What about web apps with ASP.NET? Is there a payment due when I host my application or do I just pay for the technology?

Comment: That's exactly it.  Nothing in .net requires payment - only the tools.

Comment: Should this be in the Community Wiki?

Comment: thanks for answering, and why Community Wiki? it's a question with answers not a discussion! I don't see your point in that

Comment: "I have heard that .NET is not free and that I have to pay Microsoft if I develop a .NET application" -- sounds like FUD or some other kind of anti-Microsoft ranting, just ignore it :)

Comment: There is a lot of this kind thing on college campuses now. My wife just finished her informatics degree at UB and I was appaled by the nearly universal anti-microsoft attitudes of the staff and the mis-information she was constantly given about MS technologies and products.

Comment: Yeah like Microsoft is a saint and does nothing to beat it's concurency in a drity way..

Comment: There is nothing you can't do in .NET for free.  There are some tools that cost money, that make it much easier to develop solutions, but you don't need those tools if you are asking this particular question.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is nothing about .NET that requires you to pay.

Often, you will hear that it is not free, but this is referring to the GNU concept of "Free" as in "freedom", not free as in price (or, in their words, .net is free as in beer but not free as in freedom).

You can use your student license to create .net applications.  You can also download VS 2008 Express Edition, which is fully functional to develop.

Alternatively, you can develop in .NET using non-Microsoft products.  Mono includes a completely separate, free runtime.  There are even free IDEs available, such as SharpDevelop.

--- EDIT ----

Yes.  You can use .NET to develop and deploy a website, an application, or anything else.  There is nothing in the technology itself that requires payment.  The only thing that requires payment is certain tools (such as Visual Studio Professional Edition or the Visual Studio Team Editions).  There are lots of ways to develop with .NET for free.

For free ASP.NET development, you have two options.  The first is to use the [Mono Project's ASP.NET Implementation](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) to run your site.  This is completely free, and handles asp.net sites.

However, if you are paying for hosting, your host is paying the licensing fees for Microsoft IIS and the hosting of asp.net sites.  The cost to you is included as part of the hosting.

Comment: I wouldn't call Mono the "first" option. The easiest path for most people would be the Visual Studio Express tools.

Comment: You don't have to pay to develop, but don't you have to pay to commercially release software? I'm pretty sure, for example, that you cannot sell what you make if you made it with a student license. Not 100% sure about Express editions, but I think they used to not be for commercial use either. (IANAL, etc.)

Comment: @sahuagin that's not true.  you can deploy commercial products using community edition, though there are limitations on total allowed revenue, etc.  but you can do .net without vs without restrictions

Answer (score 23):

You have heard incorrectly.

You can develop .NET apps for free.  The compilers/SDK are free and can be downloaded from Microsoft.  The framework/runtime is free for your users.

The higher end versions of Visual Studio are not free, but Express versions are available for free.

Answer (score 13):

The [.net Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/net/) is free to [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=90&p=&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2f0%2f6%2f1%2f061f001c-8752-4600-a198-53214c69b51f%2fdotnetfx35setup.exe) and develop against.  [Visual Studio .net](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/default.mspx) costs money except for express edition, which is free, but includes the .net Framework.  The cost depends on the flavor.

ASP .net is similar--you're not paying for the framework, you're paying for a copy of Windows with IIS.

Comment: Visual Studio Express is also free (as in beer).

Answer (score 7):

Developing in .NET is free in terms of cost. The framework and the SDK cost nothing.

The tools you might use to develop a .NET application are not always free. The command line compiler that is included with every .NET framework install is free. The Visual Studio Express editions are free (and can do quite a lot). Visual Studio Standard/Professional/Team Suite is not free, it's an application you need to buy,

Your Academic Alliance versions of Visual Studio (likely Professional) however have specific restrictions. If you develop something using the AA licenced version of Visual Studio, you cannot sell it or use it for commercial purposes, or use it as part of the infrasture of any entity (including your school), until you have purchased a regular licence for the tools you used.

Basically the Academic Alliance licence says you can use the full version of Visual Studio for free, but only for learning or research. If you want to turn your research project into part of a business you'll need to pay for the products you used.

If you are trying to turn your research project into a business startup you might also look at [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/). You'll still need to pay your Visual Studio costs (unless you used Express), but Microsoft will cover the costs of all your server licences (Windows Server, Sql Server, etc) in the hopes that your startup will become a successful business (if you are successful after 3 years you need to pay for the tens of thousands of dollars in licences you got for free, if you fail you only lose the $100 enrollment fee)

Comment: I think you are mistaken, you don't need to pay for your Visual Studio costs, at least not for the first three years you use it. I have the full blown Team System and it didn't cost a penny - enrollment is simple if you qualify.

Comment: Aw that makes things a little complex here! so my VS Professional is just for learning!

Comment: Maybe that's the case (AA rules have changed a few times so I may be out of date), though even re-reading doesn't seem to clarify whether AA rules (pay for VS on use) trump BizSpark or the other way around. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic/bb250609.aspx  http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/

Comment: Heh, if you ever get a clear answer from MS on licensing, let me know ;) We're a Gold partner and it's still confusing. But yes, generally the academic licenses are for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 6):

.net is totally free, only the professional tools cost money.

Answer (score 4):

.NET is free in the sense that you don't have to pay for it.  The framework and the SDK, including the compilers can all be downloaded for no charge from Microsoft.
.NET is not free, in the sense that you can not modify it and then re-distribute it like you could an open source framework.
You also have to pay if you want to use a commecial IDE like Visual Studio.  Although there are express versions that are free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to pay for the operating systems at a minimum to develop on. Before the mono zealots chime in it's in no way shape or form at the same level of maturatiy as it's windows counterpart. After the OS cost then it's the matter of what level of IDE support you need. Yes there are free ones ( the express editions and bare bones sdk installers ) but I'd wager you'll want at least VS pro which costs.

Answer (score 1):

it's free to develop with c# & ASP.NET, but to deploy your website on IIS you have to pay(as a part of the hosting fee) as said before, and I think it's much more expensive to host ASP.NET than PHP, etc.

Am I wrong? how much should you pay for hosting an ASP.NET website?

Comment: Have you actually looked at hosting prices at hosting companies. Almost all of them charge the exact same thing for hosting basic Asp.Net and PHP sites. You may have to pay extra if you want a good SQL database instead of MySQL, but the hosting for the technologies is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I want to emphasize here, fee of VS or other development tools is not the fee of .net framework. sdk, libraries so the .net framework are all free.

Comment: Good point. And for the argument that PHP is 100% free, that's a load of bull as well. I can pay for an IDE to develop PHP just like I can for .Net. The difference is, I'm actually WILLING to pay for Visual Studio, and not for any other development IDE, because, regardless of what language you are programming for, VS is light years beyond any other programming IDE I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can build commercial applications with you academic Visual Studio. who knows if the app was built in VS pro or VS academic?

Answer (score 0):

To build apps with Microsoft .NET, you have to license Windows, which is not free, though it is often built-in to the cost of the PC, and often it is a cost you have already paid!

To run apps with Microsoft .NET, again, you must have a license for Windows.

There is no cost to use the .NET SDK to build an app.  There is no cost to deploy an app that uses .NET.  There are free tools you can use to build apps.  VS Express, emacs, Reflector, SharpDevelop, etc etc.  There are also premium for-fee tools.  Visual Studio can get very expensive in the Pro versions.

Mono is a version of .NET that runs on Windows and non-Windows platforms.